# Search by the text of a button using SearchView

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-button, searchview

I have implemented some buttons in my content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.ivmenusisla.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/allRestaurants">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:text="Blenders in the Grass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/blenders"
                    android:alpha="0.90"
                    android:id="@+id/blenders" />

                <Button
                    android:text="Breakfast to Breakfast"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btob"
                    android:alpha="0.90"
                    android:id="@+id/btob" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I also added s SearchView widget on my main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_search"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:title="search"
            app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
    </menu>
```

How can I set an action listener so that when a user clicks on the SearchView widget and types something, results are displayed based on the text of each button?

I also have this on my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Log.e("onQueryTextChange", "called");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


            // Do your task here

            return false;
        }

    });

    return true;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity 's "onCreate" function, you should construct a list containing the buttons' text.

```
List<String> textContent = new ArrayList();

... onCreate (...) {
   ...
   Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blenders);
   Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btob);

   textContent.clear();
   textContent.add(button1.getText());
   textContent.add(button2.getText());

   ...
}


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // Do your task here

        for(String text : textContent) {
           if(text.contain(query)) {
                // do what you wanna do
           }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll do as you said!